# Using values from multiple async calls and then performing calculations to push the value

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs6

I am making 4 asynchronous api calls

```
floor.entities.forEach(elementId => {
  let objTemp: any = {};

  objTemp.main = elementId.name

  let currentTempForZone;

//1st async function
   this.getCurrentValue(objTemp.main).subscribe((curr) =>
       { 
         objTemp.currentTemp = curr.rows[0].val
        }
     );
//2nd async function
    this.getDesiredHeatingTemp(elementId._id).subscribe(([des]) =>
       {
         objTemp.desiredTempHeating = des.rows[0].val.split(':')[1]
        }
      );
//3rd async function
     this.getDesiredCoolingTemp(elementId._id).subscribe(([des]) => 
        {
          objTemp.desiredTempCooling = des.rows[0].val.split(':')[1]
          }
       );

let condition;

//4th
   this.deviceHelper.getConditioningStatusForZone(elementId._id);
   this.deviceHelper.conditioningTypeSubject.subscribe(condType => {
                                  console.log(condType);
                                  condition = condType                                    
               });

if(condition == 'first' ){
     let zoneTempDiff1 = objTemp.currentTemp - objTemp.desiredTempHeating;
     let tempColor1 = this.customColors.filter(color => zoneTempDiff1 < (color.temp + 1) && zoneTempDiff1 > (color.temp - 1));
     objTemp.tempColorToInsert = tempColor1.color
    }
else if(condition == 'second' ){
     let zoneTempDiff2 = objTemp.currentTemp - objTemp.desiredTempCooling;
     let tempColor2 = this.customColors.filter(color => zoneTempDiff2 < (color.temp + 1) && zoneTempDiff2 > (color.temp - 1));
     objTemp.tempColorToInsert = tempColor2.color
      }

      floor.droppeditem.push(objTemp);
}
```

I am getting all the 3 values objTemp.currentTemp, objTemp.desiredTempHeating, objTemp.desiredTempCooling and the condition but they all are asynchronous
How can I assign value to objTemp.tempColorToInsert after doing calculations using the above 4 values.

============================================================================

```
customColors: any = [
    {
        color: '#50B3D3',
        temp: -1
    },
    {
        color: '#25CBE4',
        temp: -2
    },
    {
        color: '#25CBE4',
        temp: 0
    },
    {
        color: '#7EE2DD',
        temp: 1
    },
    {
        color: '#7EE2DD',
        temp: 2
    }
    ]
```

**Update**

I have done something like and I am getting values , just wanted to know the response will automatically be mapped to their respective element

```
   forkJoin([this.getCurrentValue(objTemp.main),this.getDesiredHeatingTemp(elementId._id),this.getDesiredCoolingTemp(elementId._id)])
        .subscribe(([current,[desiredheat], [desirecooling]])=>{
            objTemp.currentTemp = current.rows[0].val;
            objTemp.desiredTempHeating = desiredheat.rows[0].val.split(':')[1];
            objTemp.desiredTempCooling = desirecooling.rows[0].val.split(':')[1];

                let condition = 'first'

                    if(condition == 'first' ){
                        let zoneTempDiff1 = objTemp.currentTemp - objTemp.desiredTempHeating;
                        let tempColor1 = this.temperatureColors.filter(color => zoneTempDiff1 < (color.temp + 1) && zoneTempDiff1 > (color.temp - 1));
                        objTemp.tempColorToInsert = tempColor1.color
                    }else if(condition == 'second' ){
                        let zoneTempDiff2 = objTemp.currentTemp - objTemp.desiredTempCooling;
                        let tempColor2 = this.temperatureColors.filter(color => zoneTempDiff2 < (color.temp + 1) && zoneTempDiff2 > (color.temp - 1));
                        objTemp.tempColorToInsert = tempColor2.color
                    }
  })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)**

```
const all$ = [
  this.getCurrentValue(objTemp.main),
  this.getDesiredHeatingTemp(elementId._id),
  this.getDesiredCoolingTemp(elementId._id),
  this.deviceHelper.getConditioningStatusForZone(elementId._id)
]

forkJoin(all$).subscribe(response => {
  objTemp.currentTemp = response[0].rows[0].val;
  objTemp.desiredTempHeating = response[1][0].rows[0].val.split(':')[1];
  objTemp.desiredTempCooling = response[2][0].rows[0].val.split(':')[1];
  condition = response[3];
  // now while you have all 4 values
  // Do your thing here
})
```

Comment: are these 4 observables ?in all$??

Comment: hi, @joyBlanks, how can i unsubscribe the forkjoin calls once all the resposnes are received, thanks

Comment: Yes you can unsubscribe forkjoin creates an observable so you can unsubscribe as regular observable

Answer (score 2):

You can use `forkJoin` method to merge the aync calls and then when all calls complete use the subscribed valus and assign it to the `tempColorToInsert` variable.

Answer (score 2):

You should use forkJoin instead of subscribing 4 times.

An example here : [learnrxjs forkjoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

Answer (score 2):

For this purpose you can use [RxJS ZIP](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html)

And use it like so:

```
zip(asyncCall_1, asyncCall_2, asyncCall_3, asyncCall_4).subscribe(
    ([asyncCall_1_response, asyncCall_2_response, asyncCall_3_response, asyncCall_4_response]) => {
        // your code goes here
    }
```

This way only once all async calls are returned you're Observable will emit

Comment: The difference between zip and forkjoin

Comment: `forJoin` is not resistant to errors and will take only last emition of each observable while disregarding intermediate emitions if any. Seems as in your case using `zip` is safer